# Coloring Pencils (no prismacolor, only Crayola)

Tags: colored-pencils

I don't personally own any Prismacolor pencils, so, besides those, which coloring pencil is best to use when doing a project?

I have Crayola pencils (twistable and regular) and I don't know how to aproach this piece.

*It's a post apocalyptic drawing of a guy in a gas mask*

Comment: This question is too subjective and opinion-based. I would recommend [edit]ing the question along the lines of "How do I select a colored pencil brand?" or "Pros and cons of popular colored pencil brands?", where we can give more objective information (seasoned with some expert opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer Tombow (Irojiten) and Faber Castell (Polychromos) pencils. Both have a great texture on any surface and the colors are really nice. They don't break easily which is a huge plus for me.

Especially if working with different tones I like to combine these two brands as they go really well together.

In the end which brand you use depends a lot on your personal preferences and experiences. I guess you can get similar results with a lot of brands (cheaper or more expensive ones). You should go with whatever you can get your hands on and practice with those. If you find that the pencils you are using are missing some "feature" or quality that you need, then go ahead and try to find pencils which cover that gap. ;-)

The crayola ones are really good pencils, too. I do also own some and especially like to take them with me when doing quick outdoor sketches.

Have fun and good luck on your project!